# Python select specific element in JSON return wrong result [get location's code function]

Tags: python, json

Hello i'm currently writing a function to convert an address array include street name, ward name, district name and city name to an object that show the location code(the street code, ward code, district code and city code come from a json file) for each of the array element above

For example the format of the output object should look like this:

> {city_name: city_code, district_name: district_code, ward_name:
>   ward_code, street_name: street_code}

currently working on an example(the array could order randomly like only 3 element, or 4 element or element order randomly that why i used the for loop to search) location's array like so:

> ['Đường Lê Quang Định', 'Phường 11', 'Bình Thạnh', 'Hồ Chí Minh']

output:

> {'Đường Lê Quang Định': street_code, 'Phường 11': ward_code, 'Bình
>   Thạnh': district_code, 'Hồ Chí Minh': city_code}

or it could be like this:

> [ 'Phường 11','Đường Lê Quang Định','Bình Thạnh', 'Hồ Chí Minh']

output:

> {'Phường 11': ward_code,'Đường Lê Quang Định': street_code, 'Bình
>   Thạnh': district_code, 'Hồ Chí Minh': city_code}

or this:

> ['Đường Lê Quang Định','Bình Thạnh', 'Hồ Chí Minh']

output:

> {'Đường Lê Quang Định': street_code, 'Bình Thạnh': district_code, 'Hồ
>   Chí Minh': city_code}

or maybe some random house number(which will return empty string if can't find in the JSON find):

> ['house number 35', 'Đường Lê Quang Định','Bình Thạnh', 'Hồ Chí Minh']

output:

> {'house number 35': ' ', 'Đường Lê Quang Định': street_code, 'Bình
>   Thạnh': district_code, 'Hồ Chí Minh': city_code}

so the array can be any address that why i used the for loop to search each element in that array and compare to the JSON to get the location code of that specific element

the json file contain location's codes(reform_address.json) has over 10000 lines but i will post the one that i'm currently having problem with:

```
{
  "Hồ Chí Minh": {
    "cityCode":"SG",
    "districts":{
      "Bình Thạnh":{
        "districtCode":"66",
        "wards":{
          "Phường 1":"8881",
          "Phường 2":"8883",
          "Phường 3":"8884",
          "Phường 5":"8885",
          "Phường 6":"8886",
          "Phường 7":"8887",
          "Phường 11":"8889", <-correct ward_code
        },
        "streets":{
          "Đường Phạm Văn Đồng":"1433",
          "Đường Trường Sa":"1485",
          "Đường Lê Quang Định":"1428",<-- correct street_code
          "Đường Lam Sơn":"1600",
          "Đường Huỳnh Tịnh Của":"1603",
          "Đường Đống Đa":"1652",
        }
      }
    }
  }
  "Đồng Tháp":{
   "cityCode":"DDT",
   "districts":{
     "Cao Lãnh":{
       "districtCode":"721",
       "wards":{
         "Phường 1":"6898",
         "Phường 2":"6899",
         "Phường 3":"6901",
         "Phường 4":"6902",
         "Phường 6":"6903",
         "Phường 11":"6904"<- output but it's not correct ward_code
       },
       "streets":{
        "Đường Lê Quang Định":"1530", <- output but it's not correct street_code
        "Đường Nguyễn Chí Thanh":"70",
        "Đường Huỳnh Thúc Kháng":"78",
        "Đường Lê Duẩn":"89",
        "Đường Đinh Công Tráng":"99",
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

as you can see the json file has the following format:

```
{
  city_name:{
    "cityCode": city_code,
    "district":{
      district_name:{
        "districCode": district_code,
        "wards": {
          ward_name: ward_code
        },
        "streets": {
          street_name: street_code
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the function i wrote to find the location of each of the element of location's array:

```
convert.py:

def loopJson():
    arrs = ['Đường Lê Quang Định', 'Phường 11', 'Bình Thạnh', 'Hồ Chí Minh']
    with open('reform_address.json','r') as jfile:
        j_data = json.load(jfile)
    a = {}
    new_cities = {}
    for value in reversed(arrs):
        for cityName in j_data.keys():
            if value == cityName:
                new_cities[value] = j_data[value]['cityCode']
            for districtName in j_data[cityName]['districts'].keys():
                if value == districtName:
                    new_cities[value] = j_data[cityName]['districts'][value]['districtCode']
                for wardName in j_data[cityName]['districts'][districtName]['wards'].keys():
                    if value == wardName:
                        new_cities[value] = j_data[cityName]['districts'][districtName]['wards'][value]
                    for streetName in j_data[cityName]['districts'][districtName]['streets'].keys():
                        if value == streetName:
                            new_cities[value] = j_data[cityName]['districts'][districtName]['streets'][value]
    a.update(new_cities)
    print(a)

loopJson()
```

in the JSON location's code some ward and street name will be repeat but it belong to different cities

The return object of the function i got was

> {'Hồ Chí Minh': 'SG', 'Bình Thạnh': '66', 'Phường 11': '6904', 'Đường
>   Lê Quang Định': '1530'}

the third and fourth element of the object has wrong location code because 6904 and 1530 doesn't belong to Hồ Chí Minh city but it's in Đồng Tháp city

expected correct result should be :

> {'Hồ Chí Minh': 'SG', 'Bình Thạnh': '66', 'Phường 11': '8889', 'Đường
>   Lê Quang Định': '1428'}

What am i doing wrong ? any helps would be appreciate :)

**EDIT:**
i edited my question to describe more detailed what this function is doing which is it take any input array of address and find location code from a JSON file resemble that

I forgot to say that the input array could be any random element of locations in the first time i posted it so it's my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you get where you need to be. It adds each different city\dict to a list.

```
city_list = []

def loopJson():

    arrs = ['Đường Lê Quang Định', 'Phường 11', 'Bình Thạnh', 'Hồ Chí Minh']

    with open('reform_address.json','r') as jfile:

        j_data = json.load(jfile)

    for x in j_data:
        new_cities = {}
        city_name = x
        city_code = (j_data[x]['cityCode'])

        for d_name in j_data[x]['districts']:
            district_name = d_name
            district_code = (j_data[x]['districts'][d_name]['districtCode'])

        for w_name,w_code in j_data[x]['districts'][d_name]['wards'].items():
            if w_name in arrs:
                ward_name = w_name
                ward_code = w_code

        for s_name,s_code in j_data[x]['districts'][d_name]['streets'].items():
            if s_name in arrs:
                street_name = s_name
                street_code = s_code

        new_cities.update({city_name: city_code, district_name: district_code, ward_name: ward_code, street_name: street_code})
        city_list.append(new_cities)

loopJson()

print(city_list)
```

Comment: local variable 'ward_name' referenced before assignment in the new_cities.update()

Comment: Did you put new_cities.update after the 'for's? Should have 2 tab spaces before it.

Comment: Here' an example of it running, not sure what could be wrong on your end?

https://repl.it/repls/TerribleAcrobaticExams

Comment: oh yeah because i had some dependency import with the ward name in my file sorry , thank for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

You worked too hard: With `arrs`, you have the keys into the data without the need to search using the `for` loop. The best way to work this problem is to open a Python interpreter and play with the data. Here is a suggested solution:

```
import json


def main():
    with open('reform_address.json') as jfile:
        data = json.load(jfile)

    arrs = ['Đường Lê Quang Định', 'Phường 11', 'Bình Thạnh', 'Hồ Chí Minh']
    street, ward, district, city = arrs

    try:
        city_code = data[city]['cityCode']
        district_code = data[city]['districts'][district]['districtCode']
        ward_code = data[city]['districts'][district]['wards'][ward]
        street_code = data[city]['districts'][district]['streets'][street]
        converted = {city: city_code, district: district_code, ward: ward_code, street: street_code}
        print(converted)
    except KeyError as e:
        print('Address not found:', e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Notes

- Using `arrs` as the key, we can access the `city_code`, `district_code`, `ward_code`, down to the `city_code` directly
- Using these code, we can construct the `converted` dictionary which is what you want.
- If for some reason, the data in `arrs` is wrong, then we will encounter a `KeyError`, The message should tell which piece of information (city, district, ...) is not found

Comment: thank you it work, this is much more simple than using a for loop to do the search. Cheer :))

Comment: wait i forgot something what if the location array ordering random? like ward come before street, that why i use the value in my function just to check if it match

Comment: What you have is a nested dictionary, not an array (list). The order does not matter. Try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: i edited my question ,sorry i'm not talking about the json dict but the input arrs which won't always be street, ward, district, city but sometime can be ward, street, district, city or ward, district, city so right now the search function would be best cause i search for each element in arrs input for a match :) hope you understand